# QTouchEvent instead QMouseEvent on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, touchscreen, multiplatform

I am trying to handle QTouchEvent from M3 touchscreen in Qt 5.9. I use [Qt Finger Print example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-touch-fingerpaint-example.html) and it works fine on Windows 7 but on Ubuntu 16.04 I receive mouse events instead of touch events. Is it Qt's fault or wrong OS configuration?

What is more `QTouchDevice::devices().size()` always equals 0.

Comment: Are you using Wayland or X?

Comment: @Akiva I use X Server

Comment: Maybe `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents, false);` ?

Comment: @dtech it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you post on bugreports.qt.io ? It may be a platform plugin bug

Comment: I assume you have read [QTouchEvent docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html#enabling-touch-events) in detail and checked that your widgets have the [Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) set, along with what @dtech mentioned?

Comment: @nonsensickle your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [EventFilters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html) to catch touch and mouse events in multiple platforms. To doing this you have to call `installEventFilter` in the constructor of your widget and implement the `eventFilter` to filter the [QEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html) you are looking for. For example using something like this:

```
bool ECGPlot::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *ev) {
    bool ret = false;

    switch (ev->type ()) {
        case QEvent::TouchBegin:
            ret = true;
            break;

        case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
            ret = true;
            break;

        case QEvent::TouchEnd:
            ret = true;
            break;

        case QEvent::Wheel:
            ret = true;
            break;

        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
            ret = true;
            break;

        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
            ret = true;
            break;

        case QEvent::MouseMove:
            ret = true;
            break;

    }

    return ret;
}
```